# Can I create a contraint that populates a column on insert regardless of whether data is provided?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sequence

A bit of an odd requirement this one.

There is a column on a database (SQL) that is nullable.
I have a constrain in place that populates the column is null/default is provided and it populates from a sequence.

Is it possible to put a constraint in place that ignores any data provided by the insert statement and always puts in the next sequence value?

my current table/constraint is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testmembership](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [membershipno] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


alter table testmembership
add constraint DF_mytblid
default
'PREFIX-'+cast((next value for membershipseq) as nvarchar(50))
for membershipno
```

If I do the following:

```
insert into testmembership (id,name,membershipno) values (12,'test',default)
```

it yeilds the correct sequence generated value.
However, I want it to still have that value from the sequence even if i call this:

```
insert into testmembership (id,name,membershipno) values (12,'test','ignoreme')
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You can use a trigger.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you may use Computed column for this

Comment: I suppose [auto increment](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) is not a good option in this case. I would think that creating a BEFORE INSERT trigger and using a sequence would work here. But that's done different on each database type.

Comment: @jarlh sorry, stack overflow suggested the tag. I am using SQL server

Comment: What's the expected behavior when UPDATE?

Comment: I'm not that fussed on update if the value changes, it would just be the insert

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want using a constraint, but you can define a trigger that replaces the normal insert behaviour using the *instead of* option:

Something like this might work:

```
create trigger tr on testmembership instead of insert as 
  insert testmembership (id, name, membershipno)
  select id, name, 'PREFIX-' + cast((next value for membershipseq) as nvarchar(50)) 
  from inserted;
```

Comment: Interesting idea, is there much of a performance impact using this sort of trigger?

Comment: @doodlleus Triggers have adverse effect on performance in general, but since the logic here isn't complex in any way I wouldn't worry about it unless you expect a need to do a very high number of operations fast.